# How to simplify updating state of Quiz component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Quiz component with two types of questions (one correct answer and questions with free answer). I need to send answers to the backend in the following format:

```
 [
  {
    questionId: 'test-id',
    answers: ['answerId']// send answer id if this is question with one correct answer
  },
  {
    questionId: 'test-id',
    answers: ['answerId']// send answer id if this is question with one correct answer
  },
  {
    questionId: 'test-id-2',
    freeAnswer: 'some text' // send freeAnswer if it is open ended question
  }
...
]
```

I create two handlers: one for text area and one for radiobuttons,

```
  const handleOptionChange = ( question, answer) => {

      onChangeQuestionAnswer(question, answer, 'oneCorrectAnswer')
  }

  const handleFreeAnswerChange = (value, question) => {
     onChangeQuestionAnswer(question, value, 'freeAnswer')
  }
```

And one general handler in parent component to process all answers:

```
const [chosenAnswers, setChosenAnswers] = useState([])



 const handleChangeQuestionAnswer = (
    questionId,
    answerId,
    type
  ) => {
    const foundedId = chosenAnswers.find(item => item.id === questionId)

    if (!foundedId) {
      if (type === 'oneCorrectAnswer') {
        setChosenAnswers([...chosenAnswers, { id: questionId, answers: [answerId] }])
      } else {
        setChosenAnswers([...chosenAnswers, { id: questionId, freeAnswer: answerId }])
      }
    } else {
      const newResultArray = chosenAnswers.map(item => {
        if (item.id !== questionId) {
          return item
        }

        if (type === 'oneCorrectAnswer') {
          return {
            ...item,
            answers: [answerId]
          }
        } else {
          return {
            ...item,
            freeAnswer: answerId
          }
        }
      })

      setChosenAnswers(newResultArray)
    }
  }
```

Then I just sending `chosenAnswers` to API. This approach works, but it looks weird and overhead for me, can I somehow simplify this logic?

Comment: Hey I submitted a refactored version of code that removes some duplicate logic and follows best practices (with some comments on thought process). Hope that helps.

Comment: Switch/case is the same as if/else, and it doesn’t solve the problem. I suggest you read these two books: Refactoring and clean code

Comment: @chonnychu I'll do it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The data and the handlers look clean. In the parent component, there is some logic repeated four times (returning the `answer` or `freeAnswer` keys and associated string or array). I would put that into a variable:

```
  const answerForm =
    type === 'oneCorrectAnswer'
      ? { answers: [answerId] }
      : { freeAnswer: answerId };
```

Then spread that variable when you call `setChosenAnswers` or return objects when you map over `chosenAnswers`. Ex.

```
    [...chosenAnswers, { id: questionId, ...answerForm }]
```

That also allows you to remove two of the if/elses because aside from that duplicate logic the conditions are the same.

You could also modify the `foundedId` if/else in two ways:

1. **Reverse the order and remove negative conditional** (considered not a best practice by some).
2. **Change if/else to ternary** - more deterministic, less room for side effects.
3. **Set result to variable** (`answerToSubmit`) and then call `setChosenAnswsers` once instead of twice with that variable

```
  const answerToSubmit = foundedId
    ? chosenAnswers.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== questionId) return item;

        return {
          ...item,
          ...answerForm,
        };
      })
    : [...chosenAnswers, { id: questionId, ...answerForm }];
```

**Full code:**

```
const [chosenAnswers, setChosenAnswers] = useState([]);

const handleChangeQuestionAnswer = (questionId, answerId, type) => {
  const foundedId = chosenAnswers.find((item) => item.id === questionId);

  const answerForm =
    type === 'oneCorrectAnswer'
      ? { answers: [answerId] }
      : { freeAnswer: answerId };

  const answerToSubmit = foundedId
    ? chosenAnswers.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== questionId) return item;

        return {
          ...item,
          ...answerForm,
        };
      })
    : [...chosenAnswers, { id: questionId, ...answerForm }];

  setChosenAnswers(answerToSubmit);
};
```

If you had more answer types, I might suggest a switch statement, but overall this reduces duplicate logic and makes code more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code by using ES6 feature to make it easy to read, and maybe split change answer handler of textarea and radiobutton is more better?
A function should only do one thing, don't use too many if/else statement, if it's me, I will change the code like this:

```js
const handleOptionChange = (question, answer) => {
    onChangeSelectionQuestionAnswer(question, answer)
}

const handleFreeAnswerChange = (value, question) => {
    onChangeFreeTextQuestionAnswer(question, value)
}

const handleChangeFreeTextQuestionAnswer = (questionId, answer) => {
    const targetAnswer = chosenAnswers.find(item => item.id === questionId)

    let newAnswers = [...chosenAnswers]

    if (!targetAnswer) {
        newAnswers.push({ id: questionId, freeAnswer: answer })
    }
    if (targetAnswer) {
      const idx = newAnswers.indexOf(targetAnswer)
      newAnswers[idx].freeAnswer = answer
    }
    
    setChosenAnswers(newAnswers)
}

const handleChangeSelectionQuestionAnswer = (questionId, answerId) => {
    const targetAnswer = chosenAnswers.find(item => item.id === questionId)

    let newAnswers = [...chosenAnswers]

    if (!targetAnswer) {
        newAnswers.push({ id: questionId, answers: [answerId] })
    }
    if (targetAnswer) {
      const idx = newAnswers.indexOf(targetAnswer)
      newAnswers[idx].answers = [answerId]
    }
    
    setChosenAnswers(newAnswers)
}
```

You will find `handleChangeFreeTextQuestionAnswer` and `handleChangeSelectionQuestionAnswer` has duplicate code, so you can  simplified further more

```js
const handleChangeFreeTextQuestionAnswer = (questionId, answer) => {
    handleChangeQuestionAnswer(questionId, answer, 'freeAnswer')
}

const handleChangeSelectionQuestionAnswer = (questionId, answerId) => {
    handleChangeQuestionAnswer(questionId, [answer], 'answers')
}

const handleChangeQuestionAnswer = (questionId, newValue, valueField) => {
    const targetAnswer = chosenAnswers.find(item => item.id === questionId)

    let newAnswers = [...chosenAnswers]

    if (!targetAnswer) {
        newAnswers.push({ id: questionId, [valueField]: newValue })
    }
    if (targetAnswer) {
      const idx = newAnswers.indexOf(targetAnswer)
      newAnswers[idx][valueField]= newValue
    }
    
    setChosenAnswers(newAnswers)
}
```

If you want to add a new question type in the future, you only need to add a new `handleChangeXXXQuestionAnswer`  function, then adjust the answer format and update field, and call `handleChangeQuestionAnswer`, you don't need to add more and more if/else or switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already have separate handler anyways, I suggest just passing the formatted answer object to your `handleChangeQuestionAnswer`. For example, you can change your dedicated question type handlers to the following

```js
const handleOptionChange = ( id, answer) => {
  onChangeQuestionAnswer({id, answers: [answer]})
}

const handleFreeAnswerChange = (freeAnswer, id) => {
  onChangeQuestionAnswer({id, freeAnswer})
}
```

As for the general handler you can use an object instead of an array to keep track of the answers. With an object you can use the same spread syntax as you did with the array. And thanks to the other update above you can really simplify your general handler to one line. Please the updated function below

```js
const [chosenAnswers, setChosenAnswers] = useState({})

const handleChangeQuestionAnswer = (question) => {  
  setChosenAnswers(answers => {...answers, ...{[question.id]: question}})  
}
```

**Note:** I use a handler to update the state to avoid any race condition. AFAIK this is always the preferred way to update the state with the hook setter function.

When submitting the answers to the server use `Object.values()` to get values as an array. Ex:

```js
Object.values(chosenAnswers)
```