# Error when calling a function from the child to change the state of the parent

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, web

I am attempting to change the state of the parent to something upon a button click in the child component. The issue is that when I click the button I get the error *Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Quiz`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Quiz`*

- ***E******ssentially, what I am trying to do is have a couple of buttons with statements on them. When a button is clicked the statement that is on the button is passed to the parent state, which in this case is the choices[1-4] and answers[1-4].***

My App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import components
import Quiz from './components/Quiz'

function App() {
  //states
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("Ready to start?");

  //what question we are on
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  //buttons that display the available answers to choose from 
  const [choice1, setchoice1] = useState("choice1");
  const [choice2, setchoice2] = useState("choice2");
  const [choice3, setchoice3] = useState("choice3");
  const [choice4, setchoice4] = useState("choice4");

  // final answer for each question
  const [answer1, setAnswer1] = useState("")
  const [answer2, setAnswer2] = useState("")
  const [answer3, setAnswer3] = useState("")
  const [answer4, setAnswer4] = useState("")



  const nextQuestion = () => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      setQuestion((prev) => "question 1")
    } else if (counter === 1) {
      setQuestion((prev) => "question 2")
    } else if (counter === 2) {
      setQuestion((prev) => "question 3")
    } else if (counter === 3) {
      setQuestion((prev) => "question 4")
    } else if (counter === 4) {
      setQuestion((prev) => "question 5")
    } else {
      setQuestion((prev) => "complete")
    }

  }

  const finalAnswer = (param) => {
    if (counter === 1) {
      setAnswer1(param);
    } else if (counter === 2) {
      setAnswer2(param);
    } else if (counter === 3) {
      setAnswer3(param);
    } else if (counter === 4) {
      setAnswer4(param);
    } 

  }


  const incrementer = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
    console.log(counter);
    nextQuestion();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Quiz question={question} counter={incrementer}
        nextQuestion={nextQuestion} choice1={choice1}
        choice2={choice2} choice3={choice3} choice4={choice4} finalAnswer={finalAnswer} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Quiz.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Quiz = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                {props.question}
            </h1>
            <button onClick={props.finalAnswer(props.choice1)}>{props.choice1}</button>
            <button onClick={props.finalAnswer(props.choice2)}>{props.choice2}</button>
            <button onClick={props.finalAnswer(props.choice3)}>{props.choice3}</button>
            <button onClick={props.finalAnswer(props.choice4)}>{props.choice4}</button>
            <button onClick={props.counter}>next</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Quiz
```

Comment: You might need to wrap `finalAnswer` in useCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here

> `<button onClick={props.finalAnswer(props.choice1)}>{props.choice1}</button>...`.

You're not actually assigning the function, you're calling the function `finalAnswer(choice)` and which is trying to change parent`(App)` state while `rending` in progress, That's why you're seeing that warning.

You just need to wrap the `finalAnswer` in a callback.

Try like this

```
<button onClick={() => props.finalAnswer(props.choice1) }>{props.choice1}</button>
... and all for others.
```

**Note:** There's better way to do your thing, try to find out easy solution instead of handling `state` individually.

There's a [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101641/how-to-simplify-updating-state-of-quiz-component-in-react), you can find the easy solution.

Comment: Hey, There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101641/how-to-simplify-updating-state-of-quiz-component-in-react) just asked by someone